# Trying to make a VERY simple CMS with PHP and MySQL, can't get the data to output

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

I was trying to make a VERY simple CMS for a website for a personal project. It's my first time using MySQL, and one of my first using PHP, so it's kind of a learning experience. According to everybody I've asked, though, this should work. However, all it outputs is the `<h1></h1>`. I've checked everything on my database and table, the column names are right. I'm not trying to make anything to add to the database just yet. I just want to be able to read, and even a simple proof-of-concept isn't working.

If it matters, I'm using 000webhost for my web hosting.

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "****";
$mysql_database = "****";
$mysql_user = "sql_blog";
$mysql_password = "*****";

$link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

if (!mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $link)) {
echo 'Database error';
exit;
}

$sql_statement = ('SELECT * FROM Blog_Entries');
$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);
while ($curr_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<h1>' . $result['Title'] . '</h1>';
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Most of that code is copied from http://guy-lecky-thompson.suite101.com/build-a-blog-or-cms-with-php-a55246 but like I said, it looks like it should work...

Comment: Never use select * in code. It looks as if your column name isn't 'Title'.

Comment: Additionally depending on the mysql server, the table and column names are case sensitive.

Comment: Never put your credentials in a public web forum. BAD security. Change your username and password NOW NOW NOW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your while loop.

```
 echo '<h1>' . $result['Title'] . '</h1>';
```

Should be

```
 echo '<h1>' . $curr_row['Title'] . '</h1>';
```

When you iterate through the rows you need to use the row, not the pointer to the resultset.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($curr_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<h1>' . $result['Title'] . '</h1>';
}
```

Change to:

```
while ($curr_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<h1>' . $curr_row['Title'] . '</h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
echo '<h1>' . $result['Title'] . '</h1>';
```

to

```
echo '<h1>' . $curr_row['Title'] . '</h1>';
```

$result is the handle to the entire result set that your query returned.  $curr_row is the row you've pulled out of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo '<h1>' . $result['Title'] . '</h1>';
```

to

```
echo '<h1>' . $curr_row['Title'] . '</h1>';
```